# How to show that $A$ is a closed subspace of $C([0,1])$ and that $(A,\|\cdot\|)$ is a Banach Space?

Tags: functional-analysis

Given $A:=\{f \in  C([0, 1]) \mid f(0) = 0\}$ and the uniform norm on $C([0,1]):
\Vert f \Vert := \max\{|f(t)| : t \in [0,1]\}.$ How do I prove that $A$ is a closed subspace of $(C ([0, 1]), \Vert·\Vert)$ and that $(A,\Vert·\Vert)$ is a Banach Space?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to show some marginal effort.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? If you describe your efforts people are more likely to give you a suitable answer.

Answer (score 2):

However, you should notice that both of your questions are connected :

- If you show that $A$ is a closed subspace, (and provided you can admit that $ \mathcal C([0,1]) $ is a Banach space with respect to the infinite norm), then it is a Banach space as a closed subset of a Banach.
- To show is is closed, you have various approaches. Hint : could you show that $A$ can be seen as the preimage of some closed space ($\{ 0 \}$) for a particular (continuous) function? Then you should be able to use some theorem to get your result.